# WebServices Consumes JSON data with Silverlight 5

Tags: c#, json, web-services, silverlight

First of all, I'm using the View-ModelsViews-Model and I'm new to Silverlight.

I would like to get JSON Data from an other application on Internet and display it into a grid.

On the ViewModelPage I have this :

```
    public void SetBasicAuthHeader(WebRequest req, String userName, String userPassword)
    {
        string authInfo = userName + ":" + userPassword;
        authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo));
        req.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + authInfo;
    }

    public void Request()
    {
        // create the http request
        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp("Myurl");
        httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
        httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json";
        SetBasicAuthHeader(httpWebRequest, "mylogin", "mypassword");


        // get the response asynchronously
        httpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse(OnGetResponseCompleted, httpWebRequest);
    }

    public void OnGetResponseCompleted(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)ar.AsyncState;

        // get the response
        var response = httpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(ar);

        // deserialize json
        var jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Users));
        var responseObject = (ListUtilisateursRest)jsonSerializer.ReadObject(response.GetResponseStream());

        // display on the view
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke();
    }
```

I have also created a Portable Library with this :

```
[DataContract]
public class Users
{
    [DataMember(Name = "Users")]
    private List<String> UsersList = new List<String>();
}
```

I know i have to put something into the "BeginInvoke" to bind the data to the views, but I have no idea how to do that, Could you help me ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Take an example.

1. You got the list of users received from other. OK!
2. You create listbox in XAML, Binding to your Data, here is List Data `<ListBox DataContext="{Binding Data}" ></ListBox>`
3. You can edit generated item template of listbox to define how each User showed on the listbox.
4. Dont forget INotifyPropertyChanged.